# Extension of Gordon's comparison inequality to subgaussian processes?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, measure-concentration

"Theorem A" in this paper by Y. Gordon: 
http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~mjunge/Comps/Gordonm.pdf
is a comparison inequality for Gaussian processes:

Is there an analogue of this result for subgaussian processes? By "analogous" I mean to have the process $X_{ij}$ subgaussian with bounded subgaussian norm, and the same conclusion up to constant factors.

That is, something that would recover Talagrand's comparison inequality for $n=1$ (Corollary 8.5.3 in http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/teaching/2015-16/626/HDP-book.pdf).

Comment: Analogous in what sense? Its assumption or conclusion?

Comment: I edited the question to explain.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood what you mean by analogous, in that direction you need to consult some treatise on Sobolev/Orlicz spaces. I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I think a closest inequality in controlling the deviance between two processes is [McDiarmid’s Inequality](http://cs.nyu.edu/~rostami/ml/2007/ashish-mcdiarmid.pdf), and it has an extension which also applies to subgaussian random variables [Concentration in unbounded metric spaces and
algorithmic stability](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.1007.pdf).

You need to describe what kind of analogy you are looking for in order for me to add more.